# Is this sentence 私の家族の一人は痩せて、かわいい the correct translation of

Tags: grammar, translation

Is the sentence

> 私の家族の一人は痩せて、かわいい

a correct translation of

> One of my family members is thin and cute

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than やせていて, I think ほそくて would be a better description.
やせていて almost sounds negative, as in "too thin".

私の家族の一人はほそくてかわいい。

Google ほそくてかわいい　and you'll get a bunch of images of thin and cute models and idols.

Comment: I did some thinking, and I realized we could slightly alter  your phrasing  to make the Japanese translation more natural sounding: 
私の家族には細くて可愛い人がいる。
It's not the exact same nuance though, so it might not work for you, depending on the intent behind the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "私の家族の一人は" is correct. Although it might feel more natural to specify which one(brother, sister, father, etc...).

However, the following change should be made :

> 痩せて > 痩せていて

Adding the "いて" is needed to reflect the ongoing state of being thin rather than the plan or the action of loosing weight.

Comment: Thank you for your answner but I have a question, what's the point in attaching two te-form verbs ?   痩せて is already reflecting an ongoing state of being thin? isn't it?

Comment: @Kopurakusu the second one is the te form of the iru that you add after the first te form to make it ongoing. A te form without the iru after is not ongoing, just a plain te form, that can be used for various things(like chaining up an adjective in this case.)